# how to specify mask for decimal places CMFCMaskedEdit

Tags: mfc

How I can specify two decimal point mask using CMFCMaskedEdit.

I want to validate/allow only integer with two decimal points.

Thanks,

Comment: And, what have you tried on your own?

Comment: The `CMFCMaskedEdit` control cannot be used to validate decimal numbers. You'll have to write your own.

Comment: Make sense.It works for me